# Overloaded operator undefined

Tags: c++

I'm following a book called: Game Physics Engine Development. In the book, the author create a custom type(real) to allow him to switch easily between float an double without changing the entire program. He then overload the *= operator to allow a vector dot product.

```
typedef float real;
#define RealSqrt sqrt
#define RealPow powf;
```

EDIT: And here's the vector class.

```
class Vector3D
    {
    public:
        real x;
        real y;
        real z;

    void operator *=(const real value)
          {
            x *= value;
            y *= value;
            z *= value;
          }
    }
```

My problem is that when I use the macro(RealPow) that I defined with my *= operator, Visual Studio highlight an error telling me that the operator *= is undefined for such parameters. (velocity is a vector)

```
velocity *= RealPow(damping, duration);
```

But what I don't understand is than when I write it directly with powf, there's no problem.

```
velocity *= powf(damping, duration);
```

EDIT: The error that it gives me is: No operator "*=" matches these operands: Vector3D *= float_cdecl(float _x, float _y)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And when you edit your question to include the MCVE, also please include the *complete* error output of the compiler, in full and unedited.

Comment: Run the compiler with `-E` with g++ or clang, and see the preprocessed output.

Comment: The error I see in Visual Studio is that you're not passing enough parameters for the free function version of that operator.  Where do x, y, and z come from?  Was this supposed to be a member function? `error C2803: 'operator *=' must have at least one formal parameter of class type` and `error C2805: binary 'operator *=' has too few parameters` along with errors for the missing x, y, and z.

Comment: I just wonder why you have a ';' after 'powf'???

Comment: as @Retired Ninja says operator overloading with one param is used when You define them inisde class  (user defined type ) outside calss def You should provide 2 args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your define line

```
#define RealPow powf;
```

should not have an extra semicolon at the end.